# How can I run a command with a specific AppArmor profile/hat?

Tags: apparmor

I'm hoping there exists something like sudo for AppArmor, so I can run something in a context like:

```
aado -hat my-hat command arg arg arg
```

Does this exist?

Answer (score 2):

I think this can be done by creating hardlinks to e.g. /bin/bash. You then create a profile for /bin/bash-my-hat and start your command:

```
/bin/bash-my-hat -c command '$0' arg1 arg2
```

Comment: ooh, thats clever! i'm going to try this!

Comment: Don't forget to come back and accept the answer if it does work. :)

Answer (score 0):

The `aa-exec` command can run a command with a specific named profile (or unconfined). For example:

```
aa-exec -p my-profile -- command arg arg arg
aa-exec -p unconfined -- command arg arg arg
```